# Calling google maps with multiple destinations from iOS app

Tags: iphone, uiapplication

I have not had success launching the Google maps application with multiple destinations and I have not found anything specifying if it is possible or not.

while this code works great for one destination and the users current location:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Curent+Location&daddr=San+Francisco,+CA"]]
```

`

Now with two destinations and the current users location like this does not work:

```
 UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

[app openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Curent+Location&daddr=San+Francisco,+CA+to:los+angeles,+CA"]]
```

`
the result is a route to the last destination.

I actually am currently look for a solution on the iOS and Android os since the app runs on both. Basically there will are a list of saved locations that the user can pick from to create trip to take them to one destination, where they can stop and do stuff, then continue with the navigation to the next location.